# fast way to batch convert multiple csv files into excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with .csv type files, that I need to change to .xlsx type file. This is the code I have below and I cannot get the files in my folder to be converted to .xlsx I've run the code and I don't get an error message, the code just isn't converting any csv files to xlsx files. the files in my folder are capitalized CSV files instead of lower case CSV files if that makes a difference. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ConvertCSVToXlsx()

    Dim myfile As String
    Dim oldfname As String, newfname As String
    Dim workfile
    Dim folderName As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Capture name of current file
    myfile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'   Set folder name to work through
    folderName = "C:\Users\m\Desktop\CSVtoEXCEL\"

'   Loop through all CSV filres in folder
    workfile = Dir(folderName & "*.CSV")
    Do While workfile <> ""
'       Open CSV file
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=folderName & workfile
'       Capture name of old CSV file
        oldfname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
'       Convert to XLSX
        newfname = folderName & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) & ".xlsx"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newfname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
'       Delete old CSV file
        Kill oldfname
        Windows(myfile).Activate
        workfile = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I added a backslash on the end of foldername and no dice

Comment: folderName = "C:\mp180423\Desktop\CSVtoEXCEL\" I changed the code to include the backslash but it didn't change anything

Comment: I was able to figure it out, the foldername needed an extra backslash in the front.

Comment: did you try running step by step (F8)? do that and put your mouse over variables, its a simple way to debug your code and you can isolate the problem quickly

Comment: Im asking because once you isolate the problem your question can be answered... (your workfile array might be empty, the while condition wrong etc...)

Comment: I did use F8 to walk through but I wasn't getting any error message that the folderName wasn't reading correctly, so it was difficult to determine what was wrong

Comment: but the code works, just the file name needed to be updated to the correct location

Comment: in each step, look at variables values, and see that each line of did what you expect it to do, not something else

Comment: thanks for the tip @Guy L

Comment: sure. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want!

```
Sub CSVtoXLSB2()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim CSVPath As String
Dim sProcessFile As String

CSVPath = "C:\your_path_here\"
sProcessFile = Dir(CSVPath & "*.csv")
Do Until sProcessFile = ""   ' Loop until no file found.
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(CSVPath & sProcessFile)
    wb.SaveAs CSVPath & Split(wb.Name, ".")(0) & ".xlsb", FileFormat _
        :=50, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close
    sProcessFile = Dir()   ' Get next entry.
Loop
Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: you can change   it to
 ".xlsx", FileFormat _
        :=51,
if you want to save it as xlsx